# Render a different component when REST api returns error status

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm working in a pre-existing React codebase, and I don't know React particularly well. The task at hand is to send a user to a login (or error) page if the REST api call returns a 401.

There is a service.js file that provides the fetch calls to the REST service that the application requires. These functions are called from a function style component (i.e., something like `export default function HomeComp()`), which in turn is used by a Route component in App.js.

So here is the question I am asking: **What is considered a best practice design for what, in the non-React world, would be a simple redirect to the login screen?**

My best hope was wrapping the Switch in some sort of `ErrorHandler` component, but haven't been able to work out how to push a state from my REST api functions up to that component in a manner that would ever be considered as "best practices." I've been fumbling around with Hooks, but that tends to result in React errors that seem related to "you can't do that in this function because this function isn't a component" type of problems. Which, of course, my REST calls are just functions, in an entirely separate file, so other Components in the future can potentially use them as well, so of course they aren't designed as React Components. Maybe they should be and I am just unaware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're using React Router.

Your sign in page should have its own route. When you make a request and get a 401 status, you would change to the sign in route.

This is a skeleton of that:

```
function MyComponent() {
  const history = useHistory();

  useEffect(() => {
    makeApiCall().catch(err => {
      if (/* not authorized */) {
        history.push("/login");
      }
    }
  }, []);

  ...
}
```

Obviously this looks different depending on what you're specifically doing, but the gist to detect that 401 and use the [history instance](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/history) to redirect to the `/login` route.

Comment: React Router seems correct based on the existing code -- I didn't realize there was a special name for it :) Is "history" something I need to import specifically, or is it functionality added to JavaScript in the 5 years since I last seriously tackled the language?

Comment: `history` is accessed with the useHistory hook. I recommend looking through the [React Router quick start](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start) and other documentation, it walks through everything you’ll need to know.